# Differentiate between http requests sent manually and automatically

Tags: https, http

By looking at the contents of a http request, is it possible to tell the difference between

A: http requests that have been manually sent by a user in a browser

and

B: http requests that have automatically been sent by a webpage (i.e. to obtain other resources).

What would be the best place to look?

Thanks

Comment: Generally, no. Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no:

## User Agent headers

In general both actual browsers and libraries commonly used by developers will set a User-Agent  header identifying the “browser” or library.

A request without a User Agent header is most likely generated by code rather than an actual web browser.

The commonly used libcurl library for instance does not set a default User Agent header  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERAGENT.html

Other libraries may set a User Agent header that helps you to identify the requests as made by code rather than by a person by a specific User Agent (sub) string.

But developers can decide to set any User Agent and use a header identical to that used by a real  browser so that’s not 100% reliable  ...

## Related requests

Frequently your web pages include images, style sheets and other embedded content. A real browser will almost certainly start loading that content as soon as it retrieves the main web page.

When only html gets scraped but none of the images or other content is retrieved you can conclude that the requestor is probably not a person.

## IP lookup

Not extremely reliable but a Geo IP database  can be used to get details from the IP address that made the request. An IP-address from the range used by an ISP for residential ADSL subscribers is more likely to be a person than an IP from the ranges used by a VPS provider such as Google Cloud or AWS...